# How to find the client id of an element from it's class name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, clientid

**ASP.NET**

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpt" runat="Server">
    <asp:Panel ID="myPnl" CssClass="className" runat="server"/>
</asp:Repeater>
```

**JQUERY**

The following jQuery code gets the id of each element with a specified class name.

```
$('.className').each(function () {
    var myID = $(this).attr('id');
});
```

**QUESTION**

How to find the **client id** of an element from it's class name?

**EXAMPLE**

```
$(this).attr('clientid');
```

**EDITS**

I now realise client id is not possible in this instance as the unique id generated by asp.net is the only way to ensure each panel in the repeater is unique.

**This question should be closed.**

Comment: Isn't "ClientID" the same thing as "ID"?  Just that ID is the runtime value, and ClientID is used to reference what that runtime value will be at design time?

Comment: There is nothing like `clientID`! server side generated controls generates unique ID and it's selected as a client ID to bind or execute any event!

Comment: ClientID is a markedup version of the origional ID used by asp.net to ensure uniquness

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing like `clientID` atribute, server side generated controls generates unique ID and it's selected as a client ID to bind or execute any event! Its same as ID but if you want IDs you can try `this.id`.

```
$('.className').each(function () {
    var myID = this.id;
});
```

Example: This will return you `ctph00_txt_01` kind of ID [**Just a hint**].